# Trivial and non-trivial solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is meaning of trivial solution and non-trivial solution?

What is it's relation with homogeneous equation?

---

Suppose, a question

$2x+y+2z=0$

$x+y+3z=0$

$4x+3y+bz=c$

What is value of $b$ and $c$ for trivial and non-trivial solutions?

How many trivial and non-trivial solution can we get from here?

Comment: $x=y=z=0$ is called the trivial solution. Any other solution is a non-trivial solution. You can now show some effort to answer the question and let us know if you need further help.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, then why determinant |A|=0 has non-trivial solution? It also has to be trivial solution. right??

Answer (score 0):

Hy first: if $c\neq 0$ no trivial solution for the system
If $c=0$ solving the first two equations yields $x=z$ and then in the third if $b\neq -4$ no trivial solution $x=y=z=0$ is possible.

Comment: What about homogeneous system?